# Robotics kit - Using functions by changing variables

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, raspberry-pi

I hope I explain this well enough!

I'm creating a robotics kit which sends commands from a pi to an arduino. At the moment I'm just controlling servos with it and I have test code which works. However as its for children I want to make it as simple to use as possible.

At the current time this is an analogue of my code:

```
class robot(object)
    def __init___(self):
        self.servos = [0,0,0,0]

    def set_servo(self,which_servo,what_position):
        #sends serial data
        #changes servo position in servos[]
```

At the moment I have to use the function robot().set_servo() to set a servo and robot().servos[0] to read a position.

What I would like to be able to do is. To be able to set a position AND crucially send the serial data by simply doing

```
robot().servo[0] = 10
```

this would then change the value of servo[0] (which obviously it does) but also send a serial command to my arduino. Importantly this all must be wrapped in the Robot() object so that the end user doesn't have to run any other functions say to check whether the servo list has changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

If servo consists of [property objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) this is just a matter of implementing a suitable setter. That is you should not initialize servo with integers but with suitable property objects. That is: introduce a class servo like

```
class Servo(object):
    def __init__(self, which_servo, angle = 0):
        self._angle = angle;
        self._servo_no = which_servo

    def get_angle(self):
        return self._angle
    def set_angle(self, value):
        self._angle = value
        print "replace this print statement with the code to set servo, notice that this method knows the servo number AND the desired value"

    def del_angle(self):
        del self._angle
    angle = property(get_angle, set_angle, del_angle, "I'm the 'angle' property.")
```

And then initialize your robot like

```
class robot(object)
    def __init___(self):
        self.servos = [Servo(0), Servo(1), Servo(2), Servo(3)]
```

Comment: Klien: He has set function already(set_servo). He wants function to be called automatically while assigning a value. Ideally it should be done in the way you mentioned, you can't skip calling a function.